# What should be deduced by decltype(auto) for automatically type deduced argument?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, type-deduction, type-declaration

I thought that these two functions should have had the same return type:

```
template<class T>
decltype(auto) f(T&& a){return a;}
decltype(auto) g(auto&& a){return a;}
```

Nevertheless, using gcc7, these functions verify:

```
int i;
static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(f(i)), int& >::value);
static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(g(i)), int  >::value);
```

Why are the return types of g and f different?

Comment: `decltype(auto) g(auto&& a){return a;}` is not Standard C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition

```
decltype(auto) g(auto&& a){return a;}
```

is not Standard C++. It might be part of the upcoming Concepts Lite feature. g++ provides the syntax as an extension *(even without `-fconcepts`)*.

Compiling with `-Wpedantic` in fact produces a warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]
 decltype(auto) g(auto&& a){return a;}
                  ^~~~
```

Since the behavior is not standardized yet, it is unclear whether your `static_assert` should be truthy or not - intuitively I agree that `decltype(g(i))` should be `int&` though. This could simply be a "defect" in how g++ implements *non-member function* `auto` parameters.

---

The closest Standard-compliant thing to what you're trying to do is a *lambda expression*:

```
auto z = [](auto&& a) -> decltype(auto) { return a; };
```

In the case of `z`, the `static_assert` works as expected:

```
static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(z(i)), int&  >::value);
```

Comment: It looks like they should be equivalent, [see the examples here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Abbreviated_templates).

Comment: In the tag list I specified c++1z, auto argument deduction is not included in the upcoming standard?

Comment: @Oliv No, they are part of Concepts TS, which were not included.